# MVVMCross ZXing back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, zxing

I have got a problem with  back button in MVVMCross when using zxing barcode scanner. Unfortunetly, when I press back button, there is an error: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance()' on a null object reference

When I comment metohs scan() weverything is ok.
Someone know what's going wrong?

This is my fragment scann view class:

```
  public class ScannView :  MvxFragmentActivity, IBarcodeFragmentOptions
{
    protected ScannViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel as ScannViewModel; }
    }
   public static ZXingScannerFragment scanFragment;
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        try
        {
            if (scanFragment == null)
            {
                scanFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();

                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.frameScanner, scanFragment)
                    .Commit();
            }
            scan();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        try
        {


            scanFragment?.StopScanning();
            base.OnPause();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
    }
    public void ToogleFlashLight(bool on)
    {
        if (scanFragment != null)
            scanFragment.SetTorch(on);
    }

   public void scan()
    {

        try
        {
            //  var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);
            //  var status = results[Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera];
            //   if (status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
            //   {
            var opts = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat> {
                    ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                },
                CameraResolutionSelector = availableResolutions => {

                    foreach (var ar in availableResolutions)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Resolution: " + ar.Width + "x" + ar.Height);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            scanFragment?.StartScanning(opts,result =>
               {
                   if (result == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
                   {
                       RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "Anulowanie skanowanie", ToastLength.Long).Show());
                       return;
                   }
                   MainViewModel.ScannedCode = result.Text;  //ChangePropertyToEmpty();
                   RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "Zeskanowano: " + result.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show());

               });
          //  }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
        base.OnViewModelSet();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_scann);

    }

}
```

And here in my viewmdoel I have simple method to close current viewmodel:

```
    public void ButtonBackClick()
    {
        Close(this);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like you are not shutting down the scanner properly when you are calling `Close()`.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I've tried call scannerFragment.StopScanning() before Close() but nothing changed. PRoblem is also when I press phone back button. Also, I'm stoping scannig in OnPause(), but error is after this method.

Comment: @straiser Have you solved this problem?